# How does nuget detect framework version?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, .net-framework-version

My nuget package has dll:s for different .Net framework versions. One for CLR2 and one for CLR4.

```
net20/mylibrary.dll
net40/mylibrary.dll
```

This works fine when I use a package in e.g. .Net 3.5 and .Net 4 projects.

Sometimes I have projects which work with both .Net 3.5 and .Net 4. This is handled via 2 project configurations. In one case I build the .Net 4 version from the "Debug" configuration and the .Net 3.5 version from the "Release" configuration. Both of the configurations need to use `net20` references.

My csproj file looks like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

nuget will always install the `net40` assemblies which break the "Release" build.

Currently I manually change `net40` to `net20` in the .csproj file after install/update. Is there a way to avoid the edit?

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate project for .net 4 and link the files into it.